# How to disable a Dynamics CRM field when the value changes without breaking save?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

We have a two state field called Primary that is set to either yes or no. When the field is set to no, the user should be able to change it to yes. When the field is set to yes, it should be disabled, so the user can no longer change it.

We have code in the onload event that handles this; that works just fine. The challenging case is the one where a user changes the field from no to yes and then saves the form. This should lock the field so the user can't change it back to no. We attempted to solve this by putting the following code in onsave event:

```
export function onSave() {
    var primaryControl = Xrm.Page.getControl(
            d.ConstituentAffiliation.AttributeNames.Primary.toLowerCase());
        if (primaryControl) {
            if (primaryControl.getAttribute().getValue()) {
                primaryControl.setDisabled(true);
            }
            else {
                primaryControl.setDisabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

This partly works. It does disable the field so it can no longer be changed. The save doesn't work, however, because Dynamics CRM appears not to send the values of disabled fields back to the server during the save, so the new value does not actually get saved.

Any ideas would be welcome. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the following line solves my problem:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute(d.ConstituentAffiliation.AttributeNames.Primary
    .toLowerCase()).setSubmitMode("always");
```

So the code now reads as follows:

```
export function onSave() {

    var primaryControl = Xrm.Page.getControl( d.ConstituentAffiliation.AttributeNames.Primary.toLowerCase());

    if (primaryControl) {
        if (primaryControl.getAttribute().getValue()) {
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute( d.ConstituentAffiliation.AttributeNames.Primary.toLowerCase() ).setSubmitMode("always");
            primaryControl.setDisabled(true);
        }
        else {
            primaryControl.setDisabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

I should credit this blog which was very helpful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arpita/archive/2012/02/19/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-force-submit-on-a-disabled-field-or-read-only-field.aspx

Comment: The solution has on drawback - unconditionally setting setSubmitMode("always") causes the field to appear in the Audit Log even if the value hasn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've solved it however I was curious. Have you tried using a Business Rule?  This kind of basic functionality is what Business Rules in CRM 2015 can handle quite well.

For example something like this:-
[image]

Comment: It's true, the original onsave could have been implemented as a business rule. However, all the other logic for the page was JavaScript so it seemed easier to keep everything in one place. Some of the other event handlers were too complex to implement as business rules.

Comment: I suspect, although I haven't tested this, that the business rule version of onsave would have exhibited the same problem as the JavaScript version. In other words, locking the control in a business rule would have caused the field not to be submitted to the server. If that is true, then we would need to be in JavaScript because setSubmitMode isn't available in a business rule. I may test this if I have some spare time tomorrow.